# Web Service Returning JSON Array not JSON Object

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get my web service, written in .NET MVC5, to return JSON that I can consume in an iOS app. I thought I'd already succeeded, but looking more closely at the returned data - and bear in mind that this is all new to me, so forgive my terminology - it look as if I'm getting a JSON array rather than a JSON object.

This, I think, is causing issues when I follow online tutorials which show how to convert JSON objects into dictionaries in Swift for displaying in an app. As you can see from the output sample below, my JSON begins with `[{"FirstName":"John"...`, effectively launching straight into an array of People, when I think I want it to start something like `{"People":[{"FirstName":"John"...`

How can I get the JSON returned to be an object rather than just an array of people? I'm hoping I'm nearly there and perhaps just need to change a type somewhere?

**Model:**

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PhoneNumberModel> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<PersonModel> GetAllPersons()
    {
        List<PersonModel> person;
        using (var context = new ContactsContext())
        {
            person = context.People.Include("PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberType1").ToList()
                .Select(p => new PersonModel
                {
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    DepartmentName = p.Department1.Name,
                    PhoneNumbers = p.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => new PhoneNumberModel
                    {
                        PhoneNumberTypeName = x.PhoneNumberType1.Description,
                        TelephoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber1
                    })
                }).ToList();
        }

        return person;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[{
"FirstName": "John",
"LastName": "Smith",
"DepartmentName": "Accounts",
"PhoneNumbers": [{
    "PhoneNumberTypeName": "Office",
    "TelephoneNumber": "12345"
    }, {
    "PhoneNumberTypeName": "Mobile",
    "TelephoneNumber": "54321"
    }]
}, {
    "FirstName": "Jane",
    "LastName": "Harris",
    "DepartmentName": "HR",
    "PhoneNumbers": [{
        "PhoneNumberTypeName": "Mobile",
        "TelephoneNumber": "98765"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: The generated JSON is correct - Your return type for the Action is `IEnumerable<PersonModel>` which is a collection, so it will always be converted to an Array in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetAllPersons` method returns an `IEnumerable` (i.e. a collection of `PersonModel`) so it will be serialized to it's JSON counterpart (i.e. a collection of JSON objects). If you want to wrap the collection in a JSON object, so it becomes:

```
{
   "People": [
      {
         "FirstName": "trashr0x",
         "LastName": "StackOverflow",
         "DepartmentName": "MVC",
         "PhoneNumbers": [
            {
               "PhoneNumberTypeName": "Work",
               "TelephoneNumber": "123456"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

...then simply do the same with your model in C#: make a `PeopleModel` class having a `People` property of type `IEnumerable<PersonModel>`:

```
public class PeopleModel
{
    public IEnumerable<PersonModel> People { get; set; }
}
```

You can then instantiate a `PeopleModel` instance, set `PeopleModel.People` to your `IEnumerable<PersonModel>` and `return PeopleModel` instead.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! Is it to be expected that doing this would return the data much more slowly? Because it is!

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. It normally shouldn't - I can't tell without having a look at your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `HttpResponseMessage`**

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllPersons()
{
    List<PersonModel> person;
    using (var context = new ContactsContext())
    {
        person = context.People.Include("PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberType1").ToList()
            .Select(p => new PersonModel
            {
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                DepartmentName = p.Department1.Name,
                PhoneNumbers = p.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => new PhoneNumberModel
                {
                    PhoneNumberTypeName = x.PhoneNumberType1.Description,
                    TelephoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber1
                })
            }).ToList();
    } 
    HttpResponseMessage response = 
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { People = person });
    return response;  
  }
```

**Using `IHttpActionResult`**

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllPersons()
    {
        List<PersonModel> person;
        using (var context = new ContactsContext())
        {
            person = context.People.Include("PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberType1").ToList()
                .Select(p => new PersonModel
                {
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    DepartmentName = p.Department1.Name,
                    PhoneNumbers = p.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => new PhoneNumberModel
                    {
                        PhoneNumberTypeName = x.PhoneNumberType1.Description,
                        TelephoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber1
                    })
                }).ToList();
        } 
        return Ok(new { People = person }); 
    }
```

see this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) for more info